Omega, Omega hierarchical, CFA
I have run a bifactorial CFA in R with lavaan and also extracted the omega hierarchical, but fail to calc the omega, and explained common variance for the 5factors. I tried it with the psych package, but it doesn't work. Could somebody give some advice?
model_RDS1 <- '

Factors
Factor1 =~ Q24_6 + Q24_11 + Q24_16

Factor2 =~ Q24_2 + Q24_7 + Q24_17 + Q24_22 + Q24_26

Factor3 =~ Q24_13 + Q24_18

Factor4 =~ Q24_9 + Q24_14 + Q24_19 + Q24_23 + Q24_27

gFactor =~ Q24_1 + Q24_2 + Q24_3 + Q24_4 + Q24_5 + Q24_6 + Q24_7 + Q24_8 + Q24_9 + Q24_10 + Q24_11 + Q24_12 + Q24_13 + Q24_14 + Q24_15 + Q24_16 + Q24_17 + Q24_18+ Q24_19 + Q24_20 + Q24_21 + Q24_22 + Q24_23 + Q24_24 + Q24_25 + Q24_26 + Q24_27 + Q24_28 + Q24_29

'

fit_RDS1 <- cfa(model_RDS1,

data = data, estimator = "MLR", orthogonal = TRUE)

summary(fit_RDS1, fit.measures =TRUE, standardized = TRUE)

OMEGA hierarchical
compRelSEM(fit_RDS1, return.total = TRUE)

I tried the omega function in psych package, but it doesn't work:
omega(model_RDS1, 5, n.obs=961)
#Error in m$n.obs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

